# Powershell Bulk Rename Files by Date Taken

Tags: powershell, jpeg, rename, bulk

I wrote a quick script (below) to rename files b replacing/removing things (particularly changing innate picture formats to only have the date (and adding things at the end).

Some photo formats don't have the date taken in the file name. Is there a way to alter what I have below to add date/time taken? I have looked around and have not come across anything helpful - or concise/simple. I feel like this shouldn't require 10 lines. Thanks.

```
get-childitem *.jpg | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("IMG_", "") }
```

Comment: IMHO, step 1 is finding a solution that works regardless of the number of lines. are you looking at creation time as when a given photo was taken or looking into EXIF data? different cameras, or even the same camera with a different setting may save in various name formats. perhaps consider detecting the format, then writing conversion functions to normalize each to your desired name.

Comment: Maybe powershell is not the best tool for the job you want to do either. A search of the internet gave this as an example https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php  There are probably others...use your own due diligence. I have no connection to this site, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This would put the creationtime in the filename.  Although you can easily do things like `ls | where creationtime -gt 9/13`.

```
ls *.jpg | rename-item -NewName { 
  $base, $time = $_.basename, $_.creationtime.tostring('yyyyMMdd') 
  $_.name -replace $_.basename, "$base-$time" } -whatif
```

Output:

```
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: /Users/js/foo/file1.jpg Destination: /Users/js/foo/file1-20190914.jpg".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: /Users/js/foo/file2.jpg Destination: /Users/js/foo/file2-20190914.jpg".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: /Users/js/foo/file3.jpg Destination: /Users/js/foo/file3-20190914.jpg".
```